# Getting several inputs from users using scanf

Tags: c

I am having a problem here. I am trying to get several inputs from a user and calculate the total input and the average depending on the number of days he has worked. For example, if he worked for 10 days, when he types 10, the program will ask him to enter the working hours for 10 days. The iterateArray array can only hold 30 days max and the variable days, holds the number of days entered. How can I get the values using scanf?

```
int main(void){

    printf("The program calculates the total hours worked during\n");
    printf("a specific period and the average length of a day.\n\n");
    printf("How many days:");

    scanf("%d",&days);


     do{    
          if(i==days){
             break;
             i++;
       }


     else{
        printf("Enter the working hours for day %d:",++i);
        scanf("%f",&iterateArray[0]);
         }

   }while(i<days);


}
```

Comment: Your code does not show a definition for `i` or `iterateArray`.  You should also check that the `scanf()` operations are successful, rather than simply assuming they work.  Your code indentation leaves quite a lot to be desired.  I believe you could use a `for` loop instead of a `do … while` loop and it would make your code simpler to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int days, dayCount;
    double iterateArray[30], totalWork = 0, averageWork = 0;

    printf("The program calculates the total hours worked during\n");
    printf("a specific period and the average length of a day.\n\n");
    printf("How many days: \n>");

    scanf(" %d", &days);

    if (days > 30) {
        printf("You can't work longer then 30 days!");
        exit(0);
    }

    for(dayCount = 0; dayCount < days; dayCount++) {
        printf("Enter the working hours for day %d:", dayCount+1);
        scanf(" %lf", &iterateArray[dayCount]); 
        totalWork += iterateArray[dayCount];
    }

    averageWork = totalWork / days;

    printf("\nThe total hours you worked is: %.2lf\n", totalWork);
    printf("The average length of a day is: %.2lf\n", averageWork);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ideally you should check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure it is successful.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for replying. Actually I have functions to calculate the total hours and the average, but the problem is to get the inputs. I used a single variable to get the inputs and pass it to the array, it didn't work, I used the array in the scanf, it don't work, finally I used a for loop but it didn't work

Comment: @Sagnol does my code work for you and solved your problem or what isn't working now?

Comment: Thanks alot Rizier, it does.